# Qualified operators

Tags: haskell

In GHC (without language extensions) I have to do this:

```
x = 2 Prelude.+ 1
-- valid: x = (Prelude.+) 2 1
-- invalid: x = Prelude.+ 2 1
-- also invalid: x = 2 `Prelude.+` 1
```

How to change this behavior?

Comment: Change to what? Why this behavior is not what you want?

Comment: You don't have to do any of this, just use `2 + 1`. If GHC is complaining about ambiguous occurence of `+`, then you have two conflicting definitions in scope; you probably should hide one of them. Do you want to know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [Haskell Report, section 2.4](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4):

> The qualifier does not change the syntactic treatment of a name; for example, Prelude.+ is an infix operator with the same fixity as the definition of + in the Prelude

So, assuming the `Prelude` qualifier is just an example and you want to use the syntax shown in the comments, I don't think there is a way.